# non EU family member having pre-settle status under EU settlement scheme can bring dependent?

Tags: dependent-visa, eu-settlement-scheme

I  am a non EU family member of my Italian father living in the UK. I have pre-settle status under EU settlement scheme until NOV-2024. I want to bring my dependent (wife) from my home country Bangladesh. What kind of visa I can apply for my wife?

Comment: Is she coming before the end of the year?  I don't know whether it matters, but it might.

Comment: @phoog i want to apply early possible, but i dont know which kind of visa I have to apply.